# Agendamento de tarefas no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de médio porte, é uma das funções é enviar SMS aos clientes do sistema. No laravel nós temos como usar os cron nova para agendar uma tarefa para ser executada a cada 10 minutos ou a cada semana e por aí vai!

Meu problema!

Eu preciso enviar um SMS pro cliente assim que ele se cadastra e dentro do meu Dashboard o Admin pode escolher quanto tempo depois esse SMS será enviado

Ou seja, se o administrador definir que o SMS será enviado uma hora depois do cadastro! Toda vez que um cliente se cadastra eu tenho que executar essa tarefa uma hora depois!

Se um cliente se cadastra 12:00 eu envio 13:00
Se outro se cadastra 13:30 eu envio 14:30

Como fazer esse tipo de agendamento no laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta do Bulfaitelo é uma possível solução sendo que outra seria atrasar o processamento de um Job. É uma solução que requer pouca intervenção no sistema que já possas ter desenvolvido, desde que já estejas a usar Queues.

Segundo a documentação (https://laravel.com/docs/queues#delayed-dispatching), podes definir quanto tempo depois o sistema deve executar um Job. Assim, imaginando que tens um Job chamado `ProcessNewRegisterSmsNotification` podes fazer o seguinte, imediatamente depois do método que regista o user:

```php
ProcessNewRegisterSmsNotification::dispatch($user)->delay(now()->addHour());
```

Onde tem `now()->addHour()` podes substituir pelo valor que o administrador definiu em backoffice.

Comment: Obrigado José! Acredito que essa seja a melhor solução, fiz um pequeno teste aqui e funcionou! Vou colocar em produção pra ver se vai ter algum problema com volumes altos!

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer,

Criar uma [Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling) que execute a cada minuto (ou um outro intervalo maior), chamando um método de `SMSQueues` (por exemplo).

Esse método basicamente seria um Select que buscaria com base na hora de execução do Schedule, os sms que deveriam ser enviados, e caso retorne alguma informação envie para os destinatários.

Já no momento do cadastro, o cliente irá fazer o cadastro normalmente, porem no método de cadastro você também irá inserir na tabela de `sms_queues` (seguindo a mesma lógica da classe acima) a hora que o SMS deve ser enviado, essa hora vai ser baseado no somatório hora atual + a hora definida pelo administrador.

Creio que isso irá resolver seu problema.